# Verb to describe the action of receiving something you are not responsible for

Tags: single-word-requests

Within the context of computer science, I am trying to describe four different actions.

1. Adopt - To receive some resource that I am responsible for
2. Delegate - To pass on some resource that the receiver will now be responsible for
3. Borrow - To receive some resource that I am not responsible for
4. ?  - To pass on some resource that the receiver will not be responsible for

Is there a suitable verb which I can use to describe the scenario in #4 that is clearly distinct from option #2?

Also are there any existing computer science terms to describe the other actions? (I think delegate could also be described as a "move")

Comment: It would seem like "misdirect" is most appropriate.  (If the receiver is not responsible for it, why send it?)

Comment: @Hot Licks, yes its a bit awkward to describe but the receiver may want to inspect it, but will not have to dispose of it (Some one else will do that)

Comment: If that's your definition of *borrow*, remind me not to lend you my hedge trimmers.

Comment: So you're discussing *ownership*?

Comment: @HotLicks - Nope, we're discussing the single word for what Columbia House's business model is. Try as I might, *solicitation* doesn't fit.

Comment: Maybe the verb "forward" would work?  As in "forward an email".

Comment: Something like *foist* or *palm off*? However, they might be too negative for your context.

Comment: How about "inform: to give information to (someone)"?  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inform

Comment: Sure sounds like "ownership" in the object-oriented computer programming sense.

Comment: Dump.  Toss.  Chuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps "Lend" would work; as a complementary term to option 3 "Borrow", it should help the reader understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is

- grant

Comment: Hi, jera, This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you try to post any reference/link and its essential parts to your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

*transfer*

because it means to pass or give (and another idea is *give*) to someone or something else, but it does not say anything about whether or not the recipient will have responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not a single word but one phrase that comes to mind is **"wrong shipment"**. Pretty common issue and a jargon used in online marketing business as could be seen in the link below.

https://community.ebay.in/t5/Buying-on-eBay-India/Wrong-shipment-how-to-handle-this/td-p/11300